# jqgalscroll timer

Tags: jquery, timer, image-gallery

I'm trying to add a timer to the **jqgalscroll** plugin, the plugin has the function

```
jqimg.click(function(){
var next = n.index + 1;
if((n.index +1) == el.totalChildres) {
    el.pagination.find('[href$=0]').click();
}
else {
    el.pagination.find('[href$=#'+ next+ ']').click();
}
});
```

this is used to move to the next image in the gallery, but im not sure how i would go about calling it from the setInterval function that i have setup in my own page. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You just pull your code into a function and use it in two places:

```
var myAction = function(){
   var next = n.index + 1;
   if((n.index +1) == el.totalChildres) {
      el.pagination.find('[href$=0]').click();
    }
    else {
        el.pagination.find('[href$=#'+ next+ ']').click();
    }
}

jqimg.click(myAction);
setInterval(myAction, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just trigger the click event:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() { jqimg.click(); }, 5000);
```

Comment: but the jqimg.click() function is in the jqgalscroll.js plugin

Comment: That doesn't matter, though you may need to get the handle to jqimg yourself - instead of `jqimg.click();` it would be `$('#something').click();`

Answer (score 0):

I added this to index.html inside script tags. Does the trick. "i" is the link href

```
var i = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function() { 
    $('a[href="#'+i+'"]').click();
    i++;
    if(i == 6){
            i = 0; 
    }
}, 5000);
```